# How to handle questions about scientific computing?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) tag we regularly encounter questions asking about computational problems where [Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) is used, however the question is more about computational methods and there is a special Stack Exchange site about them, [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Latest example: *[stochastic heat equation - Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048869/stochastic-heat-equation-fortran)*

This time the OP got the answer he wanted, but this is not always the case.

In this one I went ahead and answered the question: *[periodic boundary conditions - finite differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903982/periodic-boundary-conditions-finite-differences/35914182#35914182)*

Have I done the right thing?

How should we handle these questions? When I click to vote to close as off-topic, there is no applicable reason to choose. Notably, when I click on "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network " then there is only a limited number of sites to chose from, [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) is missing.

I expect similar questions also appear from time to time in tags like [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), but I do not follow these.

Comment: Some of these beta SE sites never seem to be able to graduate, 5 questions a day just isn't very motivational to anybody.  Afaict they just gave up on shutting them down.  You didn't do wrong.

Comment: Generally when I find something that belongs on another SE that isn't a migration target, I flag it as completely off-topic and leave a comment about finding the correct SE at stackexchange.com. And yes, Hans is correct in that they no longer close down beta sites that don't get enough activity to graduate.

Comment: If you're active at Computational Science enough to be sure a question belongs there, you can link them directly to CS' help center, but many mods don't like it if you link directly to them on a question that isn't on topic on their SE.

Comment: For a second, I read that as _"Science fiction computing"_. I prepared a whole _"It's off-topic"_ rant in my head... So disappointed ;-)

Comment: One problem with a bit more scientific questions is afaik that Latex/Math stuff is not rendered easily on SO. It works however on other StackExchanges. Or has this changed in the meantime?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That a question belongs on another site does not necessarily mean that it does not belong on Stack Overflow. I think these are valid programming questions. They can be answered with answers that meet the Stack Overflow guidelines. (As opposed to Code Review questions, for example, where the answers would be too subjective for Stack Overflow.)

I think the tags applied ([numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods), [pde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pde), [differential-equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations)) do enough to distinguish the questions and highlight them for a specialized audience.

Comment: "I think these are valid programming questions." What do you mean by that? All questions about scientific computing are on-topic on SO?

Comment: I think he means that the two examples you gave on on-topic. Also, that there is a lot of crossover to be expected, especially among sites like this.

Answer (score 6):

Questions are valid on any Stack Exchange site where they are on-topic. They can be on-topic on more than one site in which case the questioner can ask them at any one of them.

However, even in that case, depending on the number and proficiency of the audience in each Stack Exchange site, the probabilities for getting an answer that solves the problem will be different.

Is this question on-topic on Stack Overflow?

At first glance, the question looks like a "why isn't this code working"-type of question where it is actually unclear if this code is working and the emphasis is on the code doing the right thing.

As such they must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

In this case it is not really clear what the desired behavior is. "am I implementing the noise correctly?" cannot be answered without specifying what correct noise would be? Some statements about the noise are given, but without knowing the underlying physical/mathematical model, the given information is (or may, I'm not certain actually) not sufficient to determine what would be the correct noise in the mathematical model used here, and therefore I tend to say that the question might be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Basically when asking "Is this the proper way" you should have made clear what the proper way would be in theory and then ask about an implementation. The asker didn't make it clear enough what the proper way in theory would be, at least to me.

An indication of the missing information in the question is also the beginning of the first answer "You appear to be using".

Another indication is that the questioner is not even sure if the code is working or not. If he would know what to expect he could check against the results of this code and would probably know (at least for some parameter sets).

"I only use the Gaussian random number y1, I do not need y2." is another hint that something is wrong. How can anyone else know which variables are needed or not needed without knowing the full mathematical model that is behind the code?

If the missing information would be given, the question would be on-topic on Stack Overflow (check of an implementation of a working problem) but might also be on-topic for example on the *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site.

If the missing information about the model is actually the problem a mathematics or computer science related Stack Exchange might be on-topic.

It depends on what the problem really is here.

Comment: I had a very similar opinion about that question.